# Using HTML5 to demonstrate how characters were written

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML5, and I'm planning to create a tool to demonstrate how a character was written by hand in correct order.

I've this code to create a Chinese character with canvas, but is there a way to draw it step by step until the whole character is complete? Using Javascript is welcome, I don't want to use gif or flash to draw so many frames.

Any idea? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas beginePath example</title>
    <script>
        function beginDemo() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("demo")
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        ctx.font = "52pt 楷体";
            ctx.fillText("字", 220, 200);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="beginDemo();">
    <canvas id="demo" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Short answer: no, unless every single stroke in the character is a glyph in the typeface you are going to use. Otherwise you will simply have to use sprites, and then rely on CSS3 animation to displace the background position after every fixed interval.

Comment: @Terry: Since he's using a canvas he doesn't really need sprites, but he needs every stroke in a drawable format. However, getting the order of strokes for many Chinese characters will take forever. I guess an SVG animation would be a little bit easier than canvas, but still a huge pile of work.

Comment: If you are asking: `is it possible to make an animation that draws the character step by step?` then the answer is *yes, provided you make the animation for every single character*. If your question is `can it be done automatically, without further information from the developer?` then the answer is no. I suggest you [check this project](http://www.kanjicafe.com/license.htm) instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I'd better find another way to do such a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [zhongwen development tool](http://zdt.sourceforge.net) (GPL) includes a large text file with stroke animation data. I remember that it was fairly easy to render the stroke shapes using [Pixi](http://www.pixijs.com), but animating them seemed challenging. At the time I made a mental note to find out from the zdt people if the data could be used and then make something to animate it nicely, but never did. Someone else had [a similar idea](https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer) which is really quite nicely done. Code is MIT license. Maybe you can use that, or at least get some ideas from it. Assuming three years on this might still be relevant to you.